# mysql - same row update query ocuurs deadlock

Tags: mysql, database, deadlock

In my application, a deadlock occurs when I run queries that are almost the same.

When I ran a **SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS**, result is same as follows. (InnoDB, mysql5.7)

```
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 41516159, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 7 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 25
MySQL thread id 266983, OS thread handle 47538359256832, query id 156835755 172.31.5.225 Test_Table updating 
Update Test_Table SET updatedAt = '2021-11-01 23:59:59' WHERE PK = 1
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 142 page no 542 n bits 0 index PRIMARY of table `Test_Table` trx id 41516159 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 68 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 23; compact format; info bits 0


*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 41516160, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 7 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 25
MySQL thread id 266996, OS thread handle 47549115574016, query id 156835795 XXX.XX.XX.XX Test_Table updating Update Test_Table SET updatedAt = '2021-11-01 23:59:58' WHERE PK = 1
 *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 142 page no 542 n bits 0 index PRIMARY of table `Test_Table` trx id 41516160 lock mode S locks rec but not gap Record lock, heap no 68 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 23; compact format; info bits 0
```

I can't understand why update query make a s-lock.

Comment: as only one seesion can update a row you get a row lock to prevent other queries to update the same row. So you should ask yourselft how to prvent that the sae row gets update in a short time

Comment: @nbk question i asked is why update query get a s-lock. i can't find any reason anywhere even mysql docs..

Comment: every action insert, update, delete causes locks, usually they are resolved in milliseconds. At this point, you start with looking into mysql error log, enabling slow query log and see if something is a miss. there thousands of threads about that, and you must dig in and see, i saw that you wrote similar update, so i thing they maybe updated the same locked rows